# What's the behavior of delete[] when the end of a string is modified

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
char * storedString = NULL; //Global Variable
void storePlainStringAndProcess(char* delimitedString) //assume string "Apple,"
{
    int len = strlen(delimitedString);
    storedString = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(storedString, delimitedString);

    storedString[len - 2] = '\0';   //removing the trailing comma, resulting string "Apple"
    //........<some code>.......//
    delete [] storedString;
}
```

I framed this code just to know the behavior of delete in such cases. What happens to the allocated space as the string is modified at the end and terminated?. Will there be a memory leak?.

Comment: Why would you even think for a second their might be? Arrays of characters don't care what data they contain.

Comment: id expect a crash here though... `int len = strlen(storedString);` since `storedString` is global you might also want to set it to NULL once you free it.

Comment: As a sidenode: you can always use `std::string` and don't care about Null terminated char arrays.

Comment: `NULL` should only be used as a pointer; otherwise, its confusing the to the reader.  (Some compilers will warn about this.)

Comment: Also: you're doing a `strlen` of `storedString1`, using the results to allocate a new `char[]`, but `strcpy`ing `delimitedString`, which could have a completely different length.

Comment: Changed the code. My mistake. I am actually measuring the 'delimitedString' length. edited now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there will not be a memory leak. When you write `new char[` the C++ runtime remembers how much memory you've allocated.

When you `delete[]`, then exactly that amount of memory is released. (To be really clear, the null terminator is **not** used to determine the amount of memory to be released.)

This is why it's so important to match `new[]` with `delete[]`. In fact, the behaviour when using `delete` without the brackets is *undefined*.

Comment: Using `delete` without the brackets would be undefined behavior.  On most current operations, in this case, it would behave exactly as using `delete` with the brackets; I can't imagine an implementation where it would leak (but I can easily imagine some where it would crash, or corrupt the free space arena).

Comment: This is why it's so important to never use `new[]` and `delete[]`, and always use something better and safer like `std::vector`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: as always a helpful clarification. I've tweaked my answer a little to reflect it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be great if you could share the related C++ spec docs.

Comment: @Prabhakaran: The ISO C++ specification is copyrighted by ISO. Besides, they're pretty unreadable in comparison to a good C++ book, e.g. Stroustrup's.